# Checking Whether Two Columns Match any Numbers from a Different Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to use one column as a sort of "criteria" column by which two other columns are searched for any numbers that match that criteria column. However, I only want a "match" to appear (TRUE/FALSE) if the two numbers in the other columns' cells both exist in the criteria column.

Here is an image as an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeMzv.png

That "criteria" column I would like to use for what numbers should be searched for in the "cited by" and "citation" columns. So basically, every time this hypothetical formula checks a pair of "cited by" and "citation" cells, it checks if there are ANY numbers from the "criteria" column that exist in both cells of that pair. If even one cell does not have a matching number from the criteria column, then I want the formula to return a "FALSE" outcome. Only when both the "cited by" and "citation" column have a number that exists in the "criteria" column do I want a "TRUE" outcome.

Hopefully that makes sense, and thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Based on the image inserted on the OP, all results will be false, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Sorry, I should have elaborated, but yes you are correct, those particular cells would all be false. The criteria column is only 300 rows long, while the other two columns are 200,000 rows long. The criteria column is therefore looking for numbers that match only those 300 numbers anywhere along those other two columns' 200,000 rows.

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer to your own question.